# VIA "Chrome 9 HC" graphics card causes blackscreen on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, xorg, drivers, graphic-card

I'm using Centos 6.5 (i386, fully updated) and get a black screen, when trying to startx. Debian was able to run a Desktop-Environment on the same machine.

My graphics card is:
CN896/VN896/P4M900 [Chrome 9 HC] (Vendor: VIA)

This driver is installed:
xorg-x11-drv-openchrome-0.3.0-3.20120806git.el6.i686.rpm ([link to driver](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/xorg-x11-drv-openchrome-0.3.0-3.20120806git.el6.i686.rpm))

I'm a beginner with linux, so all I see is, that /var/log/Xorg.0.log says there might be a problem with the drivers:

```
[   992.839]
X.Org X Server 1.13.0
Release Date: 2012-09-05
[   992.839] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   992.839] Build Operating System: c6b9 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64
[   992.839] Current Operating System: Linux cli-4-sw 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.i686 #1 SMP Thu Jun 19 19:51:30 UTC 2014 i686
[   992.839] Kernel command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_cli4sw-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=de-latin1-nodeadkeys rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd_LVM_LV=vg_cli4sw/lv_swap  LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_cli4sw/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
[   992.839] Build Date: 20 December 2013  12:05:13PM
[   992.843] Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.13.0-23.1.el6.centos
[   992.843] Current version of pixman: 0.26.2
[   992.843]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.centos.org/Documentation
   to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   992.843] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
   (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
   (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   992.843] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jul  8 13:26:18 2014
[   992.844] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   992.844] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   992.844] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   992.844] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   992.844] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   992.844] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   992.845] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
   Using a default monitor configuration.
[   992.845] (**) Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
[   992.845] (**) Option "DontZap" "true"
[   992.845] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   992.845] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   992.845] (==) Not automatically adding GPU devices
[   992.845] (==) FontPath set to:
   catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d,
   built-ins
[   992.845] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   992.845] (II) The server relies on HAL to provide the list of input devices.
   If no devices become available, reconfigure HAL or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   992.845] (II) Loader magic: 0x8271020
[   992.845] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   992.845]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   992.845]    X.Org Video Driver: 13.1
[   992.849]    X.Org XInput driver : 18.1
[   992.849]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[   992.851] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 1106:3371:1106:3371 rev 1, Mem @ 0xd0000000/134217728, 0xdd000000/16777216, BIOS @ 0x????????/65536
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[   992.855] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   992.856] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[   992.856] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   992.856] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[   992.856] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[   992.856] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[   992.856] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[   992.856] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   992.856] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   992.856] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[   992.857] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[   992.885] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   992.885]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 0.5.0
[   992.885]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   992.885] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   992.886] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   992.886] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   992.886]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 1.0.0
[   992.887]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 7.0
[   992.887] (==) AIGLX enabled
[   992.887] Loading extension GLX
[   992.887] (==) Matched openchrome as autoconfigured driver 0
[   992.887] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[   992.887] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[   992.887] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[   992.887] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   992.887] (II) LoadModule: "openchrome"
[   992.891] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/openchrome_drv.so
[   992.892] (II) Module openchrome: vendor="http://openchrome.org/"
[   992.892]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 0.3.0
[   992.892]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   992.892]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[   992.892] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   992.893] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   992.897] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   992.897]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 2.3.2
[   992.897]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   992.897]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[   992.897] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   992.898] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   992.899] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   992.899]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 0.5.0
[   992.899]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   992.899]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[   992.899] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   992.899] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   992.903] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   992.903]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 0.4.3
[   992.903]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   992.903]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[   992.903] (II) OPENCHROME: Driver for VIA Chrome chipsets: CLE266, KM400/KN400,
   K8M800/K8N800, PM800/PM880/CN400, VM800/P4M800Pro/VN800/CN700,
   CX700/VX700, K8M890/K8N890, P4M890, P4M900/VN896/CN896, VX800/VX820,
   VX855/VX875, VX900
[   992.904] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   992.904] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   992.904] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   992.904] (--) using VT number 7

[   992.913] (!!) VIA Technologies does not support this driver in any way.
[   992.918] (!!) For support, please refer to http://www.openchrome.org/.
[   992.919] (!!) (development build, compiled on Sat Feb 23 19:56:24 2013)
[   992.919] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[   992.919] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   992.919] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   992.919] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   992.919] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   992.919] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   992.919] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   992.920] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   992.920]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 0.0.2
[   992.920]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[   992.930] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such device
[   992.931] (II) CHROME(0): VIAPreInit
[   992.931] (II) CHROME(0): VIAGetRec
[   992.931] (--) CHROME(0): Chipset: P4M900/VN896/CN896
[   992.931] (--) CHROME(0): Chipset revision: 0
[   993.015] (EE) CHROME(0): [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: No such file or directory
[   993.015] (II) Loading sub module "vgahw"
[   993.015] (II) LoadModule: "vgahw"
[   993.015] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvgahw.so
[   993.016] (II) Module vgahw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   993.016]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 0.1.0
[   993.016]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[   993.016] (--) CHROME(0): Probed amount of VideoRAM = 131072 kB
[   993.016] (II) CHROME(0): VIAMapMMIO
[   993.017] (--) CHROME(0): mapping MMIO @ 0xdd000000 with size 0xd000
[   993.017] (--) CHROME(0): mapping BitBlt MMIO @ 0xdd200000 with size 0x200000
[   993.021] (II) CHROME(0): vgaHWGetIOBase: hwp->IOBase is 0x03d0
[   993.021] (II) CHROME(0): VIAMapFB
[   993.021] (--) CHROME(0): mapping framebuffer @ 0xd0000000 with size 0x8000000
[   993.132] (--) CHROME(0): Frame buffer start: 0xaf553000, free start: 0x0 end: 0x8000000
[   993.132] (II) CHROME(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
   "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   993.132] (==) CHROME(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   993.132] (==) CHROME(0): RGB weight 888
[   993.132] (==) CHROME(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   993.132] (II) CHROME(0): VIASetupDefaultOptions - Setting up default chipset options.
[   993.132] (==) CHROME(0): Shadow framebuffer is disabled.
[   993.132] (==) CHROME(0): Hardware acceleration is enabled.
[   993.132] (==) CHROME(0): Using EXA acceleration architecture.
[   993.132] (==) CHROME(0): EXA composite acceleration disabled.
[   993.132] (==) CHROME(0): EXA scratch area size is 4096 kB.
[   993.132] (==) CHROME(0): Using hardware two-color cursors and software full-color cursors.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): GPU virtual command queue will be enabled.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): DRI IRQ will be enabled if DRI is enabled.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): AGP DMA will be disabled if DRI is enabled.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): PCI DMA will not be used for XV image transfer if DRI is enabled.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): Will not enable VBE modes.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): VBE VGA register save & restore will not be used
   if VBE modes are enabled.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): Xv Bandwidth check is enabled.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): Will not impose a limit on video RAM reserved for DRI.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): Will try to allocate 32768 kB of AGP memory.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): TV dotCrawl is disabled.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): TV deflicker is set to 0.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): No default TV type is set.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): No default TV output signal type is set.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): No default TV output port is set.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): Will not print VGA registers.
[   993.136] (==) CHROME(0): Will not scan I2C buses.
[   993.136] (II) CHROME(0): ...Finished parsing config file options.
[   993.136] (WW) CHROME(0): Manufacturer plainly copied main PCI IDs to subsystem/card IDs.
[   993.136] (--) CHROME(0): Detected VIA VB8001 Mini-ITX Board (P4M900). Card-Ids (1106|3371)
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): Detected MemClk 8
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): ViaGetMemoryBandwidth. Memory type: 8
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): Detected TV standard: NTSC.
[   993.137] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   993.137] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   993.137] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   993.137] (II) Loading sub module "i2c"
[   993.137] (II) LoadModule: "i2c"
[   993.137] (II) Module "i2c" already built-in
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): ViaI2CInit
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): ViaI2CBus1Init
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): I2C bus "I2C bus 1" initialized.
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): ViaI2cBus2Init
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): I2C bus "I2C bus 2" initialized.
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): ViaI2CBus3Init
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): I2C bus "I2C bus 3" initialized.
[   993.137] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[   993.137] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[   993.137] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[   993.137] (II) CHROME(0): ViaOutputsDetect
[   993.138] (==) CHROME(0): LVDS-0 : Digital output bus width is 12 bits.
[   993.138] (==) CHROME(0): LVDS-0 : DVI Center is disabled.
[   993.138] (==) CHROME(0): LVDS Panel will not be forced.
[   993.138] (==) CHROME(0): Panel size is not selected from config file.
[   993.138] (II) CHROME(0): Output VGA-1 has no monitor section
[   993.142] (II) CHROME(0): I2C device "I2C bus 1:ddc2" registered at address 0xA0.
[   993.149] (II) CHROME(0): ViaDisplayDisableCRT
[   993.149] (II) CHROME(0): EDID for output VGA-1
[   993.149] (II) CHROME(0): Output VGA-1 disconnected
[   993.149] (WW) CHROME(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
[   993.149] (II) CHROME(0): Output VGA-1 disconnected
[   993.149] (WW) CHROME(0): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
[   993.149] (II) CHROME(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[   993.149] (==) CHROME(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   993.149] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   993.149] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   993.150] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   993.155] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   993.155]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 1.0.0
[   993.155]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   993.155] (II) Loading sub module "exa"
[   993.155] (II) LoadModule: "exa"
[   993.155] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so
[   993.156] (II) Module exa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   993.156]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 2.6.0
[   993.156]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[   993.156] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   993.156] (II) Unloading vesa
[   993.156] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   993.156] (II) Unloading modesetting
[   993.156] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   993.160] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   993.160] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[   993.160] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[   993.160] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   993.160] (II) CHROME(0): VIAScreenInit
[   993.160] (II) CHROME(0): Frame Buffer From (0,0) To (1024,32767)
[   993.160] (II) CHROME(0): Using 31999 lines for offscreen memory.
[   993.161] 3145728 bytes of Linear memory allocated at 300000, handle 165092776
[   993.161] 262144 bytes of Linear memory allocated at 600000, handle 165111608
[   993.161] 32 bytes of Linear memory allocated at 640000, handle 165085752
[   993.161] 32 bytes of Linear memory allocated at 640080, handle 165085880
[   993.161] (II) CHROME(0): - Visuals set up
[   993.161] (II) CHROME(0): - B & W
[   993.161] (II) CHROME(0): [EXA] Disabling EXA accelerated composite.
[   993.162] (**) CHROME(0): Option "MigrationHeuristic" "greedy"
[   993.162] (II) EXA(0): Offscreen pixmap area of 131072000 bytes
[   993.162] (II) EXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
[   993.162] (II)         Solid
[   993.162] (II)         Copy
[   993.162] (II) CHROME(0): [EXA] Enabled EXA acceleration.
[   993.162] (==) CHROME(0): Backing store disabled
[   993.162] (II) CHROME(0): - Backing store set up
[   993.162] (II) CHROME(0): - SW cursor set up
[   993.162] (II) CHROME(0): HWCursor ARGB enabled
[   993.162] 16384 bytes of Linear memory allocated at 641000, handle 165093848
[   993.162] 16384 bytes of Linear memory allocated at 645000, handle 165094232
[   993.162] (II) CHROME(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[   993.166] (II) CHROME(0): - Def Color map set up
[   993.166] (II) CHROME(0): - Palette loaded
[   993.166] (II) CHROME(0): - Color maps etc. set up
[   993.166] (==) CHROME(0): DPMS enabled
[   993.166] (II) CHROME(0): - DPMS set up
[   993.166] (II) CHROME(0): VIAEnterVT
[   993.166] (II) CHROME(0): VIASave
[   993.166] (II) CHROME(0): Primary
[   993.423] (II) CHROME(0): Primary Adapter! saving VGA_SR_ALL !!
[   993.427] (II) CHROME(0): Crtc...
[   993.427] (II) CHROME(0): TVSave...
[   993.427] (II) CHROME(0): VIASave
[   993.427] (II) CHROME(0): Primary
[   993.679] (II) CHROME(0): Primary Adapter! saving VGA_SR_ALL !!
[   993.679] (II) CHROME(0): Crtc...
[   993.679] (II) CHROME(0): TVSave...
[   993.679] (II) CHROME(0): ViaDisplayDisableCRT
[   993.679] (II) CHROME(0): ViaDisplayDisableCRT
[   993.679] DRM memory allocation failed -6
[   993.683] 635904 bytes of Linear memory allocated at 649000, handle 165152120
[   993.684] (II) CHROME(0): Benchmarking video copy.  Less time is better.
[   993.701] (--) CHROME(0): Timed   libc YUV420 copy... 4762460. Throughput: 124.3 MiB/s.
[   993.713] (--) CHROME(0): Timed kernel YUV420 copy... 4743212. Throughput: 124.8 MiB/s.
[   993.720] (--) CHROME(0): Timed    SSE YUV420 copy... 983023. Throughput: 602.0 MiB/s.
[   993.732] (--) CHROME(0): Timed    MMX YUV420 copy... 4608320. Throughput: 128.4 MiB/s.
[   993.732] (--) CHROME(0): Ditching 3DNow! YUV420 copy. Not supported by CPU.
[   993.739] (--) CHROME(0): Timed   MMX2 YUV420 copy... 1070837. Throughput: 552.7 MiB/s.
[   993.743] Freed 6590464 (pool 4)
[   993.743] (--) CHROME(0): Using SSE YUV42X copy for video.
[   993.743] (WW) CHROME(0): [XvMC] XvMC is not supported on this chipset.
[   993.743] (II) CHROME(0): - Done
[   993.743] (--) RandR disabled
[   993.821] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   993.833] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[   993.833] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI capable
[   993.914] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[   993.914] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[   994.506] (II) config/hal: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
[   994.506] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[   994.507] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   994.508] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   994.508]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 2.7.3
[   994.508]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   994.508]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 18.0
[   994.508] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[   994.508] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[   994.508] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[   994.509] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[   994.509] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[   994.509] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[   994.509] (**) Option "config_info" "hal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/platform_i8042_i8042_KBD_port_logicaldev_input"
[   994.509] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   994.509] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   994.509] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   994.509] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[   994.509] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "nodeadkeys"
[   994.509] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   995.067] (II) config/hal: Adding input device Sleep Button
[   995.067] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
[   995.067] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[   995.067] (**) evdev: Sleep Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[   995.068] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x3
[   995.068] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Found keys
[   995.068] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   995.068] (**) Option "config_info" "hal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer_logicaldev_input_1"
[   995.068] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   995.068] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   995.068] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   995.068] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[   995.068] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "nodeadkeys"
[   995.068] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   995.110] (II) config/hal: Adding input device Power Button
[   995.110] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   995.111] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   995.111] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[   995.111] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[   995.111] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[   995.111] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   995.111] (**) Option "config_info" "hal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer_logicaldev_input_0"
[   995.111] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   995.111] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   995.111] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   995.111] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[   995.111] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "nodeadkeys"
[   995.111] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   995.153] (II) config/hal: Adding input device Power Button
[   995.153] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[   995.153] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   995.153] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[   995.153] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[   995.153] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[   995.154] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[   995.154] (**) Option "config_info" "hal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer_logicaldev_input"
[   995.154] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   995.154] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   995.154] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   995.154] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[   995.154] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "nodeadkeys"
[   995.154] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   995.187] (II) config/hal: Adding input device ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse
[   995.187] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse'
[   995.187] (**) ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: always reports core events
[   995.187] (**) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[   995.188] (--) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x5
[   995.188] (--) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[   995.188] (--) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[   995.188] (--) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: Found relative axes
[   995.188] (--) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[   995.188] (II) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[   995.188] (II) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[   995.188] (**) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[   995.188] (**) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[   995.188] (**) Option "config_info" "hal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/platform_i8042_i8042_AUX_port_logicaldev_input"
[   995.188] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[   995.189] (II) evdev: ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[   995.189] (**) ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   995.190] (**) ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   995.190] (**) ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   995.190] (**) ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   995.220] (II) config/hal: Adding input device Macintosh mouse button emulation
[   995.220] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Macintosh mouse button emulation'
[   995.220] (**) Macintosh mouse button emulation: always reports core events
[   995.220] (**) evdev: Macintosh mouse button emulation: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[   995.221] (--) evdev: Macintosh mouse button emulation: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[   995.221] (--) evdev: Macintosh mouse button emulation: Found 3 mouse buttons
[   995.221] (--) evdev: Macintosh mouse button emulation: Found relative axes
[   995.221] (--) evdev: Macintosh mouse button emulation: Found x and y relative axes
[   995.221] (II) evdev: Macintosh mouse button emulation: Configuring as mouse
[   995.221] (**) evdev: Macintosh mouse button emulation: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[   995.221] (**) evdev: Macintosh mouse button emulation: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[   995.221] (**) Option "config_info" "hal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer_logicaldev_input_2"
[   995.221] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Macintosh mouse button emulation" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[   995.221] (II) evdev: Macintosh mouse button emulation: initialized for relative axes.
[   995.222] (**) Macintosh mouse button emulation: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   995.222] (**) Macintosh mouse button emulation: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   995.222] (**) Macintosh mouse button emulation: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   995.222] (**) Macintosh mouse button emulation: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   995.227] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:21 2014: 2665: client 1 connected from local host ( uid=0 gid=0 pid=2662 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 243
[   995.241] (II) CHROME(0): ViaDisplayDisableCRT
[   995.468] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:21 2014: 2665: client 2 connected from local host ( uid=0 gid=0 pid=2675 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 243
[   995.501] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:21 2014: 2665: client 2 disconnected
[   995.524] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:21 2014: 2665: client 2 connected from local host ( uid=0 gid=0 pid=2678 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 243
[   995.526] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:21 2014: 2665: client 2 disconnected
[   995.576] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:21 2014: 2665: client 2 connected from local host ( uid=0 gid=0 pid=2682 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 243
[   995.582] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:21 2014: 2665: client 2 disconnected
[   995.640] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:21 2014: 2665: client 2 connected from local host ( uid=0 gid=0 pid=2662 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 243
[   995.989] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:21 2014: 2665: client 3 connected from local host ( uid=0 gid=0 pid=2754 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 243
[   995.992] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:21 2014: 2665: client 3 disconnected
[   996.241] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:22 2014: 2665: client 3 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=2758 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 243
[   996.248] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:22 2014: 2665: client 3 disconnected
[   996.262] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:22 2014: 2665: client 3 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=2759 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 243
[   996.265] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:22 2014: 2665: client 3 disconnected
[   996.287] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:22 2014: 2665: client 3 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=2761 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 243
[   996.329] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:22 2014: 2665: client 4 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=2764 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 243
[   996.367] AUDIT: Tue Jul  8 13:26:22 2014: 2665: client 5 connected from local 
...
```

[complete log at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YcduxpbS)

What exactly is the problem with the existing drivers / CentOS 6.5 and how can I fix it?